# Vuex module reset state for SSR

Tags: vue.js, vuex, server-side-rendering

I am using vuejs with vuex as state management.While doing SSR,I am creating fresh instance of app with fresh instance of router and store,
to avoid  Stateful Singletons in server.More in this can be found here:https://ssr.vuejs.org/guide/structure.html#avoid-stateful-singletons.

The problem is my modules state in vuex store don't get reset.I didn't find a suitable way to create a fresh instance of a module.

I don't want to use new vmcontext in node server,also don't want to reset state of same module everytime for SSR.